# In JavaFX, binding comboBox items and table Column sort

Tags: javafx-2

I have a combo Box and a table-view. ComboBox items are filled with tables column-names. I want to bind comboBox item selection and the table column sort.
Example: If I select item say "Name" from comboBox which is at index 0 of comboBox, the 0th column of table is sorted.
Again if I sort a column in the table, comboBox selected item should update with the corresponding column name.
Right now i am achieving the table column sort based on comboBox item slection with below code.

```
private void bindComboBoxAndTableColumnSort() {
        ComboBox combo = topComboBarController.getSortCombo();
        combo.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0,
                    Number oldVal, Number newVal) {
                System.out.println("oldVal = "+ oldVal + " and newVal = "+ newVal);

                TableColumn sortColumn = null;
                SortType st = null ;
                sortColumn = table.getColumns().get( newVal.intValue() ) ;
                st =  table.getColumns().get( newVal.intValue() ).getSortType() ;
                table.getSortOrder().clear();
                if(sortColumn != null){
                    table.getSortOrder().add(sortColumn);
                    sortColumn.setSortType(SortType.ASCENDING);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

If someone can share some demo code, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need a second Listener which listens to the change to the changeorder of your TableView. Notice the need of the while loop to listen to the `paramChange`. Replace the `...` with your binding to your `ComboBox`

```
tableView.getSortOrder().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TableColumn<ColumnClass, ?>>() {
    @Override public void onChanged(Change<? extends TableColumn<ColumnClass, ?>> paramChange) {
        while(paramChange.next()) {
            if (paramChange.wasPermutated()) {
                final TableColumn<ColumnClass, ?> first = paramChange.getList().get(0);
                final String tableColumnName = first.getText();
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit**

According to the request some other approach

```
final ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>();
table.getSortOrder().get(0).textProperty().bindBidirectional(box.valueProperty());
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. I can go with this approach but this is not based on binding. I was wondering if there is a way to do this using binding ?

Comment: I edited my answer, try that one. But I rather not suggest it, since it will only trigger once. You would need to listen that the order changed.

Comment: please check your last edit. It does not work in anyway. In fact it brings up many unexpected behaviours in the table. Please check that in stand alone code if possible and re-edit or delete that change, else it will confuse others.

Comment: It works for me. As I said I do _not_ advice to use it, since you don't listen to the correct events. You cannot get the SortOrder without any Ordering implied. You have to set the sorting before-hand. Thus why I said, you need to listen to the order change. bindBidirectional is not made in particular to bind 2 components together but bind components to a model and connect the model back to other components. You should re-think your software architecture if you do not use a model for this.

Answer (score 0):

With below code, i am able to achieve what @thatslch suggested.

```
table.getSortOrder().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TableColumn<Person, ?>>(){

            @Override
            //public void onChanged( javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TableColumn<Person, ?>> paramChange) {
            public void onChanged( Change<? extends TableColumn<Person, ?>> paramChange) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(paramChange.next()) {
                    if (paramChange.wasAdded()) {
                        System.out.println("paramChanged.wasAdded() ");
                        ComboBox combo = topComboBarController.getSortCombo();
                        combo.valueProperty().bind( paramChange.getList().get(0).textProperty() );

                    } 
                }

            }
```